# Where are heaven and hell located?

Tags: heaven, hell

According to Christianity, where are heaven and hell located?

It used to be believed (and is generally depicted) that hell was below ground and heaven is above the clouds (as in you assend to heaven much like a dove) and you go down to hell. The angels fly down from heaven with their wings.
In many cathederals angels and heaven are depicted in the clouds.

Likewise hell is thought of as the underworld much like Hades of Greek mythology.

What is the general belief now that we know the Earth is a globe travelling through space. Do Christians still believe that hell is located underground. Maybe in a hollowed out area near the lava that makes up the center of the Earth?

Or alternatively is Heaven and hell located in a parallel dimension, sort of super-imposed on top of this one. In that case would Heaven be located in the clouds and Hell underground but we couldn't see it because it was in a parallel dimension? In other words that dead people could walk around the real world like ghosts but nobody could see them?

Or would they be in an entirely different Universe? If so, would Heaven and Hell be located both in the same Universe or separate Universe?

I suppose the last possibility is that Heaven and Hell are located completely in the imagination of an omnipotent being, much like a computer running a vast simulation.

For people who believe in heaven and hell, what can you say about their location?

Comment: **Wait and see** seems to be an ideal term for this enquiring subject!

Comment: _Hades_ is where the disembodied souls of the wicked now are. It is not a physical location because souls do not have physical dimensions. _Paradise_ or _heaven_ is where the disembodied souls of the just are. Likewise, with regard to physical dimensions. The lake of fire will be a physical place but it does not (yet) exist. Likewise in regard to new heavens and the new earth. All of this is quite plain from the scripture.

Comment: Not sure why Heaven and Hell is off topic about Christianity? Seems like a logical question to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know many Evangelical Christians believe that heaven and hell is not a physical place and doesn't have a specific location.

However, I believe something different, I believe hell is literally beneath us and heaven above us, because (as I understand,) the bible says so:

> Which also said, Ye men of Galilee, why stand ye gazing up into heaven? this same Jesus, which is taken up from you into heaven, shall so come in like manner as ye have seen him go into heaven. (Acts 1:11 KJV)
>
> For as Jonas was three days and three nights in the whale's belly; so shall the Son of man be three days and three nights in the heart of the earth. (Matthew 12:40 KJV)

Some Christians say the Great Rift (milky way) is a crack in the barrier between heaven and our universe, caused by either the flood or a war between satan and God. This would mean heaven is outside our universe.

[image: The Great Rift]

> And all the host of heaven shall be dissolved, and the heavens shall be rolled together as a scroll: and all their host shall fall down, as the leaf falleth off from the vine, and as a falling fig from the fig tree. (Isaiah 34:4 KJV)

Comment: @Nigel. I suppose there could be two disconnected bubbles of Universe. But then there would occasionally have to be some sort of wormhole to connect the two.